# Are there subroutines in C similar to the ones in Fortran?

Tags: c, fortran

For long time I have been using Fortran and recently I decided to learn C. While I understand how functions in C work, I am having troubles finding information about how to implement something equivalent to Fortran subroutines in C. Does this concept exist at all in the C language?

Consider this Fortran code:

```
module myMod
  implicit none
  contains

    function func(a, b)
      integer :: func
      integer, intent(IN) :: a, b
      func = a + b
    end function func

    subroutine sub(a, b, c)
      integer, intent(INOUT) :: a, b
      integer, intent(OUT) :: c
      a = a * b
      b = 3 * a
      c = a + b
    end subroutine sub

end module myMod

program example
  use myMod
  implicit none
  integer :: i, j, k

  i = 1
  j = 2

  k = func(i,j)
  print*, k

  call sub(i,j,k)
  print*, i, j, k

end program example
```

The function in the module myMod would be trivial to translate into C, but what about the subroutine? Is there a way of doing something similar?

---

EDIT: for instance, the code below is not outputting what I expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void subroutine(int num1, int num2) {
    num1 -= 1;
    num2 *= 2;
    printf("this has been executed! \n");
}

int main () {

    int a = 10;
    int b = 10;

    subroutine(a,b);
    printf( "a = %d, b = %d \n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

```
this has been executed!
a = 10, b = 10
```

Instead of the expected:

```
this has been executed!
a = 9, b = 20
```

So why aren't the variables a and b modified in that void function, like a Fortran subroutine would do?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the difference of subroutine and function is (at least in this example), that the subroutine can return more than one value. In C you would use pointers for that, simply pass pointers to `i,j,k` to the function, and the function can change the values of those variables by accessing their memory location via the pointer.

Comment: a subroutine in Fortran can change the value of the variables in the main program. See my update above  for the hear of the question

Comment: "*I decided to learn C.*" move forward in your C primer to the chapters covering the "address-of"-operator (`&`) and the "de-reference"-operator (`*`), along with pointers in general.

Comment: @alk Well, I have just started with C and I when came across functions in general I realized that there was nothing immediately analogous to Fortran's subroutines, hence my question.

Comment: "*nothing analogous*" you are correct, that's why I pointed you to the C language "features" which allow you to "emulate" the missing stuff ... :-)

Comment: Your question is about C, but I thought I'd point out that in C++ you _can_ pass parameters by reference, like Fortran. I don't think it has the equivalent of `intent(OUT)`, but it does have the equivalents of `intent(IN)` and `intent(INOUT)`. In C++, you could declare your subroutine as `void subroutine(int &a, int &b)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a function to have a return type of `void`, which means it doesn't return anything.

Functions with a `void` return type may use the `return` keyword with no value given to it, but it is not required to use `return`.

You could translate the above subroutine as follows:

```
void sub(int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    *a = (*a) * (*b);
    *b = 3 * (*a);
    *c = (*a) + (*b);
    printf("a=%d, b=%d, c=%d\n", *a, *b, *c);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
sub(&i, &j, &k);
```

In C all variables are pass by value, so modifying a parameter in a function isn't reflected in the caller.

Since you want to modify the values you pass to the function you instead pass in the **address** of each variable you intend to modify using the `&` operator, giving you a pointer to each one.  Then you **dereference** the pointer with the unary `*` operator to read/write the value it points to.

Comment: Hmm, so this seems to be what I am missing. What does the `*<variable>` mean exactly? And why should I call the subroutine using `&<variable>`?

Comment: I also updated my Fortran code to make the example more obvious, removing the `print*,` from the subroutine and adding it to the main program. I suppose it would be the same as moving the `printf` in your code above

Comment: @gilberto.agostinho.f : You need to pass the parameters by reference.

Comment: @sjsam: I wouldn't use the phrase "*pass by reference*" in the context of C, as C is *always* "pass by value" (as opposed to C++).

Comment: It's all very clear now and I will read more about `&` and `*` once I get there, thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

A function need not return a value - the c alternative to a FORTRAN subroutine is to declare the function with return type `void`.

```
void function(arguments){
...
}
```

This effectively makes the function a subroutine - provided the values are passed to  the function by reference, so that the function can change the variables which are outside its scope.

In your case declare the function as

```
void subroutine(int* num1, int* num2) { 
    /* num1 stores the address of a
     * and *num1 gives the value stored in that address
     */
    *num1 -= 1;
    *num2 *= 2;
    printf("this has been executed! \n");
}
```

and call it as :

```
subroutine(&a,&b); // &a means the address of a
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you could use the C preprocessor to define macros that behave like subroutines.  For example:

```
#define subroutine(X,Y) do{ \
  X -= 1; \
  Y *= 2; \
  printf("this has been executed!\n"); \
} while(0)

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  int a = 10;
  int b = 10;

  subroutine(a, b);
  printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a,b);
}
```

Result:

```
this has been executed!
a = 9, b = 20
```

C macros are literal text substitutions.  The outer `do...while(0)` is a pretty standard "trick" for making a multi-statement macro that is is "callable" like a function, because the `while(0)` will swallow the trailing `;` and be optimized out by any compiler worth using.  The trailing `\` characetrs allow you to define multi-line macros.

Another much less widely known (and rarely used) feature of GCC (a Gnu extension, not standard C) that might give you the effect you're after in some cases, is that you *can* define a function inside of a function, and the inner function can then access locally scoped variables of the outer function.

[Gnu C Reference manual sections on nested functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Nested-Functions)

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  int a = 10;
  int b = 10;

  void subroutine(){
    a -= 1;
    b *= 2;
    printf("this has been executed!\n");
  }

  subroutine();
  printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a,b);
  subroutine();
  printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a,b);
  subroutine();
  printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a,b);
}
```

Which results in the output:

```
this has been executed!
a = 9, b = 20
this has been executed!
a = 8, b = 40
this has been executed!
a = 7, b = 80
```

Both these techniques have plenty of pitfalls and generally fall outside the realm of "best practices" in C, but either one could be a powerful tool in trying to gradually migrate code (and your thinking) from fortran to C.

Comment: These are very interesting! Of course in your second example the variables a and b will be fixed, so that calling `subroutine();` will always affect those specific two variables as opposed to a subroutine in Fortran.

Comment: Correct on the variables being fixed in the first example.  You could parameterize it like any other function, but then you're back to dbush's answer since C doesn't have *real* pass-by-reference.  The macro approach is probably more useful.

Comment: Standard C does not support nested functions.

Comment: @IanAbbott - seems you are correct sir.  This is a GCC extension, which I guess is all the more reason it's rarely used.  Updating answer to reflect this.